# Display sales_flat_order custom columns front end

Tags: magento-1.9

Trying to display a custom column from sales_flat_order in client´s panel order history. 
I already created two columns in sales_flat_order with tracking no. and carrier, but I intend to show them in order history. So the clients could easily  track their orders by clicking on the tracking no..

My early appreciations for any kind of help. Honestly I got stuck. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We have check some in our local system, and found that Magento core comment the "***TRACK ORDER***". So you have uncomment the below mentioned coding.

**File Path:** /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/sales/order/

**File Name:** *history.phtml*

**Before changing Coding:**

```
<?php /*<span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getTrackUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>&nbsp;*/ ?>
```

**After changing coding:**

```
<span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getTrackUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>&nbsp;
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Should you require any further details, then please do not hesitate to revert!!!